# python (enthoughts distribution) - run example results in runtime error

Tags: python, runtime-error, ipython

I recently installed the enthoughts distribution of python and started to go through the examples as outlined here

http://www.enthought.com/products/epdgetstart.php?platform=mac

i.e.

EPD comes with a number of examples to get you started. To run the scripts in the Examples subdirectories, simply launch IPython and type run .

I executed the following and received a run time error which I'm not sure how to interpret as I am a new to python and enoughts.

```
mycomputer:demo$ ipython

In [1]: run multiaxis_using_Plot.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/Examples/chaco-4.0.0/demo/multiaxis_using_Plot.py in <module>()
     14 from scipy.special import jn
     15 
---> 16 from chaco.example_support import COLOR_PALETTE
     17 # Enthought library imports

     18 from enable.api import Component, ComponentEditor

/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/chaco/example_support.py in <module>()
     47             pass
     48     else:
---> 49         raise RuntimeError("Can't load wx or qt4 backend for Chaco.")
     50 
     51 

RuntimeError: Can't load wx or qt4 backend for Chaco.

In [2]: 
In [2]: pwd
Out[2]: u'/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.1/Examples/chaco-4.0.0/demo'
```

Any insights on what might be going on? I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to ask the epd-users mailing list about EPD specific problems.

Comment: Blender - I think you might be right. Interesting how the EPD installation instructions make no mention of *pre-requistites*. Instead they just tell you to install their package (http://www.enthought.com/products/epdgetstart.php?platform=mac#install). At the least their examples should be specific to the software that is bundled with their distribution of python.

Comment: As described on the 64bit EPD download page, several GUI toolkits (definitely Wx, and I think Pyglet as well) are not functional when run in 64bit mode on EPD on OS X.  It is recommended that if you want to use the GUI tools on OSX, you use 32bit EPD.

Comment: Minrk -Thank you so much for bringing this to my attention. I will revert to the 32bit as I think that should be fine for my purposes. Once again thank you - I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User 'minrk' answered this question:

As described on the 64bit EPD download page, several GUI toolkits (definitely Wx, and I think Pyglet as well) are not functional when run in 64bit mode on EPD on OS X. It is recommended that if you want to use the GUI tools on OSX, you use 32bit EPD. – minrk